# Inspect unprocessed collection objects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Eclipse has a feature that represents some types of Java collections (most notably `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque`) in a simplified way in the inspect tool (also in the Variables and Expression views):

```
d = ArrayDeque<E> (id=33)
  [0] = "somevalue" (id=57)
  [1] = "someothervalue (id=59)
```

In most other classes, instead of the `[0]` and `[1]` entries, the inspect tool will show fields of the object, including their names. I'm interested in looking at the internals of a live `ArrayDeque`.

Is there a way to make the inspect tool show the real fields of the ArrayDeque, so that the output looks more like this?:

```
"d" = ArrayDeque<E> (id=33)
  elements = Object[] (id=34)
  head = 2
  tail = 4
```

I'm using Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0).

**EDIT**: I have already tried using a subclass of ArrayDeque, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way:

In `Preferences` > `Java` > `Debug` > `Logical Structures`, there is a definiton that performs `toArray()` on any `java.util.Collection` before the inspect tool shows the result.

While it is not possible to remove that default entry, you can add an entry for a more specific type:

Qualified type name: `java.util.ArrayDeque`
Description: Shows `ArrayDeque` internals
Code: `this`